# Why can't Julia identify NaN in some cases?

Tags: matrix, julia, nan

a matrix as follow is made in Julia

```
Zt=[10;20];Zb=[30;40]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 30
 40

julia> R1=[Zt Zb]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 10  30
 20  40
```

when a condition like follow is tried, it works correctly

```
R1[:,1][1]==10
true
```

but if the matrix is as follows:

```
Zt=[NaN;20];Zb=[30;40]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 30
 40

julia> R1=[Zt Zb]
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 NaN    30.0
  20.0  40.0
```

although the `R1[:,1][1]` is NaN, the condition is false

```
R1[:,1][1]==NaN
false
```

would you please tell me what the problem is?

Comment: I googled "Julia Nan" for you: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/julia-test-if-number-is-nan/25642/2 . See the last post.

Comment: see https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/mathematical-operations/#Numeric-Comparisons-1 as this is what you are probably looking for. In particular the difference between `==` and `isequal`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with arrays, and, furthermore, it has nothing to do with Julia, it's specified in the IEEE floating point standard. If you try `NaN == NaN` in Julia, Python, Matlab or any other language, you will get `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `isnan` instead:

```
isnan(f) -> Bool

Test whether a floating point number is not a number (NaN).
```

Like this:

```
julia> isnan(NaN)
true

julia> R1 = [NaN 20;
              30 40]
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 NaN    20.0
  30.0  40.0

julia> R1[:,1][1]
NaN

julia> R1[:,1][1] |> isnan
true

julia> isnan(R1[:,1][1])
true
```